# Tkinter Entry sempre captura string vazia

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, tkinter

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação com interface gráfica usando o `Tkinter`.
A interface gráfica consiste um *botão*, um *texto* e de uma *entry*, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: Interface]

A ideia é que se digite uma palavra no widget *entry* ao clicar no botão é exibida o significado dessa palavra no widget *texto*.

Meu código está organizado em duas classes: uma para a GUI e outra para a aplicação em si.

**Interface gráfica** (para reduzir código removi a parte que insere a imagem):

```
 class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        if master is None:
            return
        else:
            self.word = StringVar()
            self.word_meaning = None
            self.app_frame = Frame(master)
            self.app_frame.grid()
            self.create_app_frame()
            self.entry_widget = Entry(self.app_frame, textvariable=self.word)
            self.button_widget = Button(self.app_frame, text='Meaning', command=self.__handler_entry)
            self.text_widget = Text(self.app_frame, height=10, width=30)
            self.crete_app_frame()

    def crete_app_frame(self):    
        self.entry_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button_widget.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.text_widget.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def get_word(self):
        return self.word.get()

    def set_word_meaning(self, meaning):
        self.word_meaning = meaning

    def __handler_entry(self):
        self.text_widget.delete(0., END)
        self.text_widget.insert(END, self.word_meaning)
```

**Aplicação Lógica**:

```
class InteractiveDictionary:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            self.data = json.load(file)

    def get_meaning(self, term):
        print('-------------------')
        print(f"world is:{term}")
        print('-------------------')
        term = str(term)
        term = term.lower()
        if term in self.data:
            return self.data[term]
        else:
            return "The world you\'re looking for doesn\'t exist."
```

**Main**:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Interactive Dictionary')
    dictionary = InteractiveDictionary('words.json')
    app = Gui(master=window)
    word = app.get_word()
    word_meaning = dictionary.get_meaning(word)
    if type(word_meaning) == list:
        for i in word_meaning:
            app.set_word_meaning(i)
    else:
        app.set_word_meaning(word_meaning)
    window.mainloop()
```

A aplicação em si funciona corretamente quando exibo os resultados no terminal. Entretanto, quando tento fazer através da GUI a palavra capturada por get_word() não é passada corretamente pro método get_meaning() do dicionário. Ele passa uma `str` vazia!

Suspeito de que o erro esteja relacionado com a maneira que invoco o Tkinter na `main`. 
Alguem  tem ideia do motivo de `word` ser uma string vazia e não palavra capturada pelo widget `Entry`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código que está no main tem que estar na função __handler_entry().

```
def __handler_entry(self):
    word = self.get_word()
    word_meaning = self.dictionary.get_meaning(word)
    if type(word_meaning) == list:
        for i in word_meaning:
            self.set_word_meaning(i)
    else:
        self.set_word_meaning(word_meaning)
    self.text_widget.delete(0., END)
    self.text_widget.insert(END, self.word_meaning)
```

Comment: Se eu fizer dessa forma não estarei isolando a interface da aplicação. Além disso vc sabe explicar o por quê disso?

Comment: acho que faz sentido porque o código tem que correr quando o botão é pressionado e não no arranque

Comment: Depois de muito analisar consegui entender